# How do I get JSON data when the key has spaces in it using python and flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using a Queensland government API. The format for it is JSON, and the keys have spaces in them. I am trying to access them with python and flask. I can pass through the data required to the HTML file yet cannot print it using flask.

```
   {% block content %}
<div>
 {% for suburb in data %}
    <p>{{ suburb.Age }}</p>
    <p>{{ suburb.Manslaughter Unlawful Striking Causing Death }}</p>
 {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Above is the code for the HTML file. "Manslaughter Unlawful Striking Causing Death" is the key I am trying to access but it comes up with this error when I load the page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    req = requests.get("https://www.data.qld.gov.au/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8b29e643-56a3-4e06-81da-c913f0ecff4b&limit=5")
    data = json.loads(req.content)
    print(data)
    district=[]
    for Districts in data['result']['records']:
        district.append(Districts)
    return render_template('index.html', data=district)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Above now is all the python code I am running.

[The error that is shown on the webpage when trying to load it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq0LY.png)

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using dot notation in your template, you can access values in a dictionary like this

```
{{ suburb['Manslaughter Unlawful Striking Causing Death'] }}
```

Hopefully that solves your issue!

Answer (score 0):

In `jinja2` (which is used by `Flask` for templating) you can access dict elements like in `python`, consider following example:

```
import jinja2
temp = jinja2.Template("Value of abc is {{data['a b c']}}")
data = {'a b c': '1 2 3'}
rend = temp.render(data=data)
print(rend)
```

output

```
Value of abc is 1 2 3
```

Comment: Hi, can you please go over my post again as I have added in my python code which I forgot to do earlier.

Comment: @Squashy my answer remain valid, in your case you have to replace `{{ suburb.Manslaughter Unlawful Striking Causing Death }}` using `{{ suburb['Manslaughter Unlawful Striking Causing Death'] }}`